# Play/Stop button to control a loop

Tags: javascript, angular, button, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'd like to start and stop a loop with play and start button but it doesn't work. I've got an infinite loop when I press test button.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Vibration } from '@ionic-native/vibration';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

  isPlayed: boolean = false;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private vibration: Vibration) {

  }

  play(){
    this.isPlayed = true;
    this.test();
    console.log(this.isPlayed);
  }

  stop(){
    this.isPlayed = false;
    this.test();
    console.log(this.isPlayed);
  }

  test(){
    while (this.isPlayed == true) {
      console.log("test")
  }
}
}
```

And the HTML :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Pulse
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button (click)="play()">
    Play
  </button>
  <button ion-button (click)="stop()">
    Stop
  </button>
  <button ion-button (click)="test()">
    Test
  </button>
  {{counter}}
</ion-content>
```

Comment: *"I've got an infinite loop"* - well `while (this.isPlayed == true)` will either never run or run forever, so that seems unsurprising.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'd think the obvious response from OP would be "But doesn't the `stop()` function do that?"

Comment: Yes but I thought that when I click on stop button it will update the boolean value. How I can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `this.isPlayed` to `false` (or a `falsy` value) for the `while` loop to stop. But you can't run `stop()` because `console.log` is constantly executing.

Maybe you can test it with `setInterval`:

```
  private interval;

  test(){
      if (this.interval) {
          return;
      }

      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
          if (this.isPlayed) {
              console.log('playing');
          } else {
              console.log('stopped');
          }
      }, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I did that but it doesn't work. I can't press any buttons when the loop starts.

Comment: It's doing too much work (`console.log` is occurring constantly). Maybe you can test it with `setInterval`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: `  play(){
    this.isPlayed = true;
    while (this.isPlayed == true){
      setInterval(console.log("test"), 2000);
    }

  }

  stop(){
    this.isPlayed = false;
    console.log(this.isPlayed);
  }
}`

I did that but it doesn't work, I can't use the stop button. The loop keeps looping.

Comment: Remove the `while` loop, otherwise you're running `setInterval` over and over, constantly creating new timers. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think while loop wont work. you can try with try with setInterval and clearInterval

```
 public timer;

   play() {
        this.timer= setInterval(function () {
             console.log("test") // this is inside your loop
        }, 100);
    };

    stop() {
        clearInterval( this.timer);
    };
```